# What are the requirements to stage a hunk from any Magit diff buffer?

Tags: magit

I cannot stage a hunk with `magit-stage` in any `*magit-diff` buffer except the `*magit-diff` buffer created via status buffer.  Magit says `"user-error: Cannot stage committed changes"`.

I mean, I cannot stage a hunk in a `*magit-diff` buffer created from

1. `M-x magit-diff-dwim` in a source file
2. `M-x magit-diff-popup` then `d` in a source file
3. `M-x magit-diff` neither in a source file nor in a `*magit` buffer

However, I *can* stage a hunk in a `*magit-diff` buffer created from

1. `M-x magit-diff-dwim` in a `*magit` buffer
2. `d` then `d` in a `*magit` buffer

I found this because I often want to diff my editing file and I felt that `magit-status` and `d` `d` is a bit tedious and wanted to by-pass `magit-status`.  What am I missing?

I'm using magit `2.11.0-236-g1c69e9e9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you stage a change, then you tell Git to take what is currently in a file in the working tree and put it in the index (also known as the staging are), so that you can later create a new commit from that.

Obviously you cannot stage a change that is already staged. It is also not possible to stage a change that is already committed. While it might be technically possible in some cases that a change that lives on another branch applies to the index cleanly and can therefore be applied to the index directly, that's not really what staging means and Magit disallows it to avoid user mistakes.

So the question becomes *How to show the unstaged changes without going through the status buffer?*

In all first 1 through 3 you end up calling `magit-diff` eventually, whose purpose is to show you the differences between two commits - not the unstaged changes.

Maybe `magit-diff-dwim` should instead display the unstaged changes when invoked from a file buffer, but that will have to be investigated.

Currently you have to use `M-x magit-diff-unstaged` or `C-c M-g D u` to show the unstaged changes directly from a file buffer. The latter requires that you have enabled `magit-file-mode` (do so by enabling `global-magit-file-mode`).

Comment: Thanks! I somehow thought that `magit-diff` calls `git diff` without any arg, even though it asks me which commit I want to diff against.  Just for the test I patched `magit-diff-dwim` to call `magit-diff-unstaged` for the default case and works like a charm.  I don't diff two commits while I'm editing my source code but do `git diff` a lot.  So, if by any chance, `magit-diff-dwim` is changed to call `magit-diff-unchanged` would be nice.  `git diff` without any arg does show you unchanged diff and if you wan to see staged diff, you need `--cached`.